# VSCode extension API: enable intellisense for codeblocks in JSDoc

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, jsdoc

I'm trying to add Intelisense features to JSDoc code blocks, so it does include code completion and validates syntax and types inside of those blocks:

````js
/**
 * Ensures that the word starts with capital later
 * ```jsx
 * console.log( capitalize('hello') ) // Would be cool to have autocompletion here
 * console.log( capitalize(42) ) // And to highlight error here
 * ```
 */
function capitalize(word: string) {
  return word.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}
````

Any ideas on how to achieve it, as I only found `registerCompletionItemProvider` but I see no options to use it to add completion to JSDoc

Answer (score 0):

Look at the extension [JSDoc markdown highlighting](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bierner.jsdoc-markdown-highlighting) which can provide syntax highlighting for `ts` and `js` files (use `ts` in that codeblock) - but not completions or validations.  Maybe something in there can help you.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking at it but highlighting is already enabled and I only cannot find how to add completions and validations